# How can we make an arg be optional only if the type mapped to it is undefined?

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters, mapped-types

For example, if we have the following code,

```
type Events = {
    SOME_EVENT: number
    OTHER_EVENT: string
    ANOTHER_EVENT: undefined
}

interface EventEmitter<EventTypes> {
  on<K extends keyof EventTypes>(s: K, listener: (v: EventTypes[K]) => void);
}

declare const emitter: EventEmitter<Events>;

emitter.on('SOME_EVENT', (payload) => testNumber(payload));
emitter.on('OTHER_EVENT', (payload) => testString(payload));

function testNumber( value: number ) {}
function testString( value: string ) {}
```

which works ([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20type%20Events%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SOME_EVENT%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OTHER_EVENT%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ANOTHER_EVENT%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20EventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20on%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20listener%3A%20(v%3A%20EventTypes%5BK%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20declare%20const%20emitter%3A%20EventEmitter%3CEvents%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20emitter.on('SOME_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testNumber(payload))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20emitter.on('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testString(payload))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20testNumber(%20value%3A%20number%20)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20testString(%20value%3A%20string%20)%20%7B%7D)), how can we make it so that calls to emit do not require the second arg for the `ANOTHER_EVENT` event?

For example, I can add the following line and it works:

```
emitter.emit('OTHER_EVENT', 'foo')
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Events%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SOME_EVENT%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OTHER_EVENT%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ANOTHER_EVENT%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20EventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20on%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20listener%3A%20(v%3A%20EventTypes%5BK%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20emit%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20v%3A%20EventTypes%5BK%5D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20emitter%3A%20EventEmitter%3CEvents%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aemitter.on('SOME_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testNumber(payload))%3B%0D%0Aemitter.on('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testString(payload))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testNumber(value%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0Afunction%20testString(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aemitter.emit('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20'foo')))

But if I want to call `emit` with `'ANOTHER_EVENT'`, I'd like to do it without the second arg:

```
emitter.emit('ANOTHER_EVENT') // ERROR, expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

which gives an error because it expects the second arg. ([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Events%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SOME_EVENT%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OTHER_EVENT%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ANOTHER_EVENT%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20EventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20on%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20listener%3A%20(v%3A%20EventTypes%5BK%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20emit%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20v%3A%20EventTypes%5BK%5D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20emitter%3A%20EventEmitter%3CEvents%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aemitter.on('SOME_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testNumber(payload))%3B%0D%0Aemitter.on('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testString(payload))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testNumber(value%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0Afunction%20testString(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aemitter.emit('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20'foo')%0D%0A%0D%0Aemitter.emit('ANOTHER_EVENT')))

To make it work, I have to write:

```
emitter.emit('ANOTHER_EVENT', undefined)
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Events%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SOME_EVENT%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OTHER_EVENT%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ANOTHER_EVENT%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20EventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20on%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20listener%3A%20(v%3A%20EventTypes%5BK%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20emit%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20v%3A%20EventTypes%5BK%5D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20emitter%3A%20EventEmitter%3CEvents%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aemitter.on('SOME_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testNumber(payload))%3B%0D%0Aemitter.on('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testString(payload))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testNumber(value%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0Afunction%20testString(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aemitter.emit('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20'foo')%0D%0A%0D%0Aemitter.emit('ANOTHER_EVENT'%2C%20undefined)))

How can we make the second arg not required only for the case where we call `emit` with `'ANOTHER_EVENT'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuples in rest arguments to change the number of arguments (and even their optionality) based on the first argument.

```
type Events = {
    SOME_EVENT: number
    OTHER_EVENT: string
    ANOTHER_EVENT: undefined
}

type EventArgs<EventTypes, K extends keyof EventTypes> = EventTypes[K] extends undefined ?[]:[EventTypes[K]]
interface EventEmitter<EventTypes> {
    on<K extends keyof EventTypes>(s: K, listener: (...v: EventArgs<EventTypes,K>) => void);
    emit<K extends keyof EventTypes>(s: K, ...v: EventArgs<EventTypes,K>);
}

declare const emitter: EventEmitter<Events>;

emitter.on('SOME_EVENT', (payload) => testNumber(payload));
emitter.on('OTHER_EVENT', (payload) => testString(payload));

function testNumber(value: number) {}
function testString(value: string) {}

emitter.emit('OTHER_EVENT', 'foo')

emitter.emit('ANOTHER_EVENT')
```

Comment: Holy moly, that's awesome! Thanks Titian!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the second argument optional by using a `?`:

```
type Events = {
    SOME_EVENT: number
    OTHER_EVENT: string
    ANOTHER_EVENT?: undefined
}

interface EventEmitter<EventTypes> {
    on<K extends keyof EventTypes>(s: K, listener: (v: EventTypes[K]) => void);
    emit<K extends keyof EventTypes>(s: K, v?: EventTypes[K]);
}

declare const emitter: EventEmitter<Events>;

emitter.on('SOME_EVENT', (payload) => testNumber(payload));
emitter.on('OTHER_EVENT', (payload) => testString(payload));

function testNumber(value: number) {}
function testString(value: string) {}

emitter.emit('OTHER_EVENT', 'foo')

emitter.emit('ANOTHER_EVENT')
```

I don't think it's possible to have it optional based on the input of the first argument. In that case you just need two different methods.

Comment: Hello Arno, apparently it is possible! See Titian's answer.